# Software to upload files automaticalled to a server from a NAS hard drive

Tags: cloud-service, cloud-storage, uploader, web-hosting-control-panel

I have a hard drive that is connected as a NAS, it records CCTV footage 24x7. I want the contents of the dive to be uploaded on to a hosting server which I have with GoDaddy.

The NAS drive is accessible using an external IP and connected using TP-Link Archer C1200 router.

A thing that comes to mind is running a CRON job on the server and get the files. But that will require me to code PHP as I have not done that in a while I am not looking to venture in that direction.

Is there a script or software that I can use to achieve this?